# Visa type selection on British Visa application form

Tags: visas, uk, ghanaian-citizens

What type of visa do I need to select on the application form when attending British Army Assessment? I'm coming from a Commonwealth country.

Comment: I see from your history that you are a citizen of Ghana, I think it's better mentioning that then only "Commonwealth Country"

Answer (score 7):

[Standard Visitor](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) as has already been mentioned in the Title of two of your questions in this long series, where I note one of the answers includes:

> now is not the time for you to visit the UK. Finish your studies, get a stable job, and give it another shot, preferably with the aid of a qualified solicitor.

Comment: Indeed I don't have much faith that this OP is going to follow the advice given, therefore I see little point in continuing to provide it!

Answer (score 6):

You are, presumably [since this is not your first application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86660/uk-standard-visitor-visa-application-what-do-the-questions-mean), filling out the [Standard Visitor Application](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa) to attend your army assessment and you have arrived at a screen like this...

[image]

Select 'Business' (as shown) and click 'Save and Continue'.  The next screen will ask about the purpose of your business visit.  Select 'Other' and complete the text field like this...

[image]

Click 'Save and Continue'.  The rest of the application should be straight-forward from that point.

---

Note: Sandboxing the application form is OK.

Comment: "Sandboxing the application form is OK." What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidRicherby it means it's ok to look at the form and see how it interacts with the end user. They are not bothered by it.